# How do I view last pages output in debugger

Tags: debugging, google-analytics

I have events set to fire throughout the website on button and link clicks etc.

For this particular button, on click, the page loads, displays for a second the GA Debugg output and then redirects to a new page before I've had a chance to read the output from the button click event.

Is there a way in GA Debugger to view the last pages output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest installing the ObservePoint plugin - you can enable a "persistent" mode that won't clear the console on page refresh.

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/lKLkVzXtUv5vKaUkGr7XcuDp4fPfKpjd9vS7xl0Ci9N7WUY1Jvt6t4CNfxWLqYn6pOMG1j9F=s640-h400-e365-rw

ObservePoint doesn't format the GA params as nicely as the debugger, but it's serviceable.